# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync local development

Tags: office-js

I am currently developing an Outlook add-in and as part of this, I need to present a dialog via the `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` method. The dialog is displaying fine and the user can interact with it and the elements inside.

Once they are ready to proceed, I need this information to be passed back down to the main add-in and I am doing this via the `Office.context.ui.messageParent` function. In production/staging, this would run no problem but during development I am running the add-in on my local machine and pushing the app manifest to a hosted Exchange server in our QA infrastructure.

As a result, when I try and call the `messageParent` event, it fails, as the docs state calls using this method have to be on the same domain. I cannot patch my hosts file otherwise I would loose access to the Exchange server.

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you host the dialog on the local machine as well? This link may be helpful: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/382 See Ricky's post. Also note this documentation about AppDomains: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#specify-domains-you-want-to-open-in-the-ad-in-window

Comment: I had AppDomains in there but there was no effect, at least initially. After several unloadings and reloadings, it started to work, every so often the issue returns but then I just bounce the app a few more times and it seems to come back to life, so for now, it's workable.

Comment: what error/failure does messageParent return when this fails?